# API REST for sending emails with attachment

Tags: java, rest, api, email

I'm implementing a service to send emails thought a REST API and I don't know how to deal with the attachments in a restfull way.

Any ideas about how the interface should be? maybe 2 calls, one with the mail info (subject, content, etc) and other one with the file as multipart/form?

Comment: Have you got the answer for this?

Comment: I am looking for a solution for this problem, too and it cannot find a working example via google.

Answer (score 3):

You can send the whole e-mail with attachments as multipart/form - including both sender, receivers, body and attachments as various form fields in one single request.